# New to Firebase and swift. Having trouble connecting Firebase to Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

So I am new to swift and xcode so please have mercy. So basically I am trying to connect my project in xcode to Firebase. I am using a blank single view application template and have not bothered with adding any buttons or more view controllers. I am just testing it and trying to connect it to Firebase. So the problem I am having is is the app succeeds in compiling, but then as soon as the application opens in the simulator, it gives me a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. I don’t know what I am doing wrong. I have followed all of the installation instructions correctly. I went to Firebase and configured the app with the bundle indentifier. I added the Google-Service.plist file into xcode. I succesful installed all of the pods into my project. I go into the app and add

`import Firebase`

`FIRApp.configure()`

into the delegate swift file. I save the project and close it. I open the app workspace file (the one it recommends to open) And then without adding anything to the project or adding any user interface options, I immediately run the project, it says build succeed and then instantly crashes and gives me the `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` error. Does anybody have any ideas of what this is? I don’t know what I am doing wrong. I can’t move forward with swift and firebase if I can’t even configure it correctly. Can you please figure this out?

Here is the description of the error it gives me:

`TestAppWithJack[71791] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2017-01-14 17:06:19.456 TestAppWithJack[71791:2160021] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '[FIRApp configure] could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you make sure that the google plist is specifically called GoogleServices-Info.plist? If it isn't specifically that name, then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put `GoogleServices-Info.plist`?  If you dragged it to the wrong place, that could be why it was giving this error because it cannot find the file...  Drag `GoogleServices-Info.plist` under your `info.plist` it should be fine then.